# how to display data if a field having integer value as well as text in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

code:

```
<?php
if($affiliated == '')
{
    echo $affiliated;
}
else
{
    $sql = "select * from all_university where university_id = '$affiliated'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $short_name = $row['short_name'];
    }
}
```

?>

In my database table having field name affiliated and it having two different value in different row one row having 'integer' value and another having 'text' value. I want to display different value i.e. if $affiliated having integer value it print integer else print text. So, how can I fix this problem ?

Thank You

Comment: can you show what you tried @kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check `$affiliated` is `numeric` or not and check my comment at every line

```
//check for integer
    if (is_numeric($affiliated)) {
        //condition for integer
        //  any number multiply by 1 equal to that number
        $where = " WHERE concat('',university_id * 1) = university_id";
    } else {
        //condition for text
        $where = " WHERE concat('',university_id * 1) != university_id";// here use not equal to condition
    }
    $sql = "select * from all_university" . $where;// pass $where accouding to avove condition
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $short_name = $row['short_name'];
    }
```